# jquery soundcloud play/stop

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

How can I add the CSS-Class "playSound", during the track plays?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {
        var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));

        /*widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function()
        {
            //console.log('Ready...');
            jQuery(".checkSound").removeClass('stopSound').addClass('playSound');
        });*/

        jQuery('.playSound').click(function()
        {
            widget.toggle();
            jQuery(".playSound").addClass('stopSound');
        });

        jQuery('.stopSound').live(function()
        //jQuery(".stopSound").live("click", function()
        //jQuery('.stopSound').click(function()
        {
            jQuery(".stopSound").addClass('playSound').removeClass('stopSound');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide more background or explanation of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used SoundCloud, but it appears that you are trying to use the same element to both play and stop.  If that is the case, this should work:

```
jQuery(".playSound,.stopSound").click(function(){
    jQuery(this).toggleClass("playSound stopSound");
    widget.toggle();
});
```

The click event will presumably be bound to a single element.  The selector `.playSound,.stopSound` is to make sure it selects the element regardless of what class it starts out with.  `.toggleClass()` will remove class if they are in the list or add classes if they are not.  And I'm assuming `widget.toggle()` was working as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution :-)